# CSS equivalent of DOM focus()

Tags: html, css, dom

I want to set the focus on a button on particular event.
The pseudo code for this can be,

```
if (event == "EventX") {
  document.getElementById('myAnchor').focus();
}
```

is there a CSS equivalent for `document.getElementById('myAnchor').focus();`?

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the state of an element using CSS. While CSS can style elements based on specific states, it cannot actually trigger those states. To do that, you use JavaScript, not CSS, since the DOM APIs are implemented in JavaScript, not CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I think am getting confused here, as @Paulie commented, I think what you are looking for is to autofocus an element on load than **you cannot do that with CSS**, if you want, you need can use `autofocus` attribute on the element you want to get the focus on, like

```
<input type="text" autofocus />
```

---

If you want to style the focused element then you need to use `:focus` pseudo

```
input[type=text]:focus {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2egrS/)

As I read your `id` it says `myAnchor` so you can write your selector like — to make it more specific

```
#myAnchor:focus {
    /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Comment: Does that actually set the focus? I don't think that it does...it styles the element IF it has focus...NO?

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry, I misunderstood the question, he wants autofocus attribute?

Comment: I think  he want's to target an element by ID and set it as having focus...Not possible with CSS as far as I know except, as you say, by autofocus

Comment: @Paulie_D I see, will edit my answer accordingly, thanks